# Increasing sequence of closed subspaces of $L^2$ and error estimate of a product of orthogonal projections

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, interpolation

We define  an increasing sequence of closed subspaces
\begin{align*}
V_{0} \subset V_{1} \subset V_{\ell} \subset \dots
\end{align*}
of $L^2(I)$ where $I=(0,x_{max})$, and each $V_{\ell}$ is equipped with a $L^{2}$ basis $ \{\phi^{\ell}_i\}_{i=1}^{m_{\ell}} $ ( $\phi^{\ell}_i$ are piece-wise polynomials of order $p$). I define two types of  orthogonal projections

\begin{align*}
 P_L : & L^2(I) \rightarrow V_L\\
&f \rightarrow P_L f
\end{align*}
and  a nested projection for  $\ell\leq L$

\begin{align*}
 P_{\ell,\ell-1} : & V_{\ell}\rightarrow V_{\ell-1}\\
& f^{\ell}  \rightarrow P_{\ell,\ell-1} f^{\ell}=\tilde{f}^{\ell-1}
\end{align*}

I have a problem where I am interested on deriving an upper bound estimate for

\begin{align}
\mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} \tilde{f}^{\ell}- \tilde{f}^{\ell-1} \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^2(I)}^2.
\end{align}

A tentative way I did, is the following
\begin{align}
\mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} \tilde{f}^{\ell}- \tilde{f}^{\ell-1} \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^2(I)}^2 &=
 \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}\tilde{f}^{\ell}- P_{\ell,\ell-1} \tilde{f}^{\ell} \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2 \nonumber \\
 &\leq  \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}\tilde{f}^{\ell}-  f \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2+  \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} f - P_{\ell,\ell-1} \tilde{f}^{\ell} \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2 \nonumber\\
 & \le \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} \left( P_{\ell+1,\ell} \dots P_{L,L-1}  P_{L}\right) f -  f \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2+  \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} f- \left( P_{\ell,\ell-1} P_{\ell+1,\ell} \dots P_{L,L-1} P_{L} \right) f \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2 \nonumber\\
 & \le C h_{\ell-1}^{2p+2}  \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|} f^{(p+1)} \mathrel{\Big|} \mathrel{\Big|}_{L^{2}(I)}^2,
\end{align}
where $h_{\ell-1}$ is the discretization mesh size of $V_{\ell-1}$, and where I used the interpolation error estimate as an upper bound.

I am not sure if this is correct, or if there are sharper bounds. Any hint or reference in this regard. Thanks.